# .html() not working in tizen

Tags: javascript, jquery, tizen, tizen-web-simulator

I am trying to change the contents of a `div` using `jquery` in `Tizen`. When I am using `.html(htmlString)` it is having no effect, whereas if I use `.text()` the contents are  replaced, but HTML is not parsed, as is the behaviour of `.text()`. Can someone please suggest a workaround/a point where I am missing , so that `.html(htmlString)` works correctly in `Tizen web simulator`.

The code is:

```
<script language="javascript">
function a()
{
var w='<b>'+
restaurantName+
"</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;"+
   '<span class="badge">'+
   userRating+
   "</span>"+
   "<br/>"+
   address.replace("_","<br/>")+
   "<br/>"+
   "<b>Food for 2</b>"+
   "<br/>"+
   price+
   "&#8377;"+
   '<div id="map_canvas">'+
   '</div>';
sessionStorage.setItem("docHTML",w);
location.assign('restaurant.html');

}
</script>
```

function `b()` which is called on `onload() event` of `restaurant.html`

```
<script language="javascript">
function b()
{
var contentToSet=sessionStorage.getItem("docHTML");
$("#detailDiv").text(contentToSet);
sessionStorage.removeItem("docHTML");

}
</script>
```

In both of the pages, `jquery` is loaded correctly.

Thanks

Comment: might try creating a textarea and sticking the html returned from storage in it. Perhaps it is getting corrupted when stored?

Comment: nope I did a console.log and the data is stored correctly , retrieved correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out that `sessionStorage` was not carrying data to another page/tab. So changed

```
sessionStorage.setItem("docHTML",w);
```

to 
`localStorage.setItem("docHTML",w);` in `function a()`
and in `function b()` retrieved the same with

```
var contentToSet=localStorage.getItem("docHTML");
localStorage.removeItem("docHTML");
```

Thanks a lot everyone.